# iOS view push transitions with visible next view

Tags: ios, view, push, transition

I'm trying to achieve a view transition style, the one that you can see when you slide from the left side of the screen towards the middle if you're in a view that can go back. (find any app that has a back button somewhere, and just swipe from left to right starting from the edge of the screen).

The difference between this and a regular push transition is that you can see the next AND current views on the same screen and, as you slide (if you go slowly) you can really see the view and "play" with it. But right now what it does it simply **quickly** slide (with black on the back) and show the next view.

I'd like to be able to do that between some of my views and i have no idea how to achieve that. I'm just using a custom segue that goes left to right or right to left but that's pretty much it.

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a UINavigationController and the [pushViewController:animated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:) method, then this should be the default functionality on iOS 7.0 and later. Your new UIViewController will be able to be "pulled back" by the user using a swipe right from the left of the screen.